# Get screen width and pass it to ASP control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, linechart

I can't believe I just spent 3 hours on finding the solution. It looks easy but it's just impossible.

I'm using ASP control(LineChart), and I want to set the width of the chart is same with the screen size on page load.

So these are some approaches which I did and failed. I'm not sure it's worth mention, but you can skip to #4 if you want:

1. I understand that there is no way we can get the screen size from code behind, so I create 2 hidden fields for storing screen width and screen height. I get the screen resolution from Javascript and pass it to hidden field values at document.ready, and read the value of hidden fields at Page_Load(code behind). So far so good. but there is 1 problem, which the page_load always render first before the Javascript; hence my value of my hidden fields always return null.

Javsscript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     width = $(window).width();
     height = $(window).height();
     document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_hfWidth').value = width;
     document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_hfHeight').value = height;
});
```

Code Behind:

```
LineChart1.ChartWidth = hfWidth.Value;
LineChart1.ChartHeight = hfHeight.Value;
```

2. I call the Javascript from code behind, didn't work too. because cannot find the Hidden fields control.
3. I create 2 hidden fields and 1 hidden button. no function at Page_Load, I moved these function to another function call getScreenSize(), I trigger the button click at document.ready. The button clicked, I was able to get the screen size, but it cause  unlimited postback. (button click trigger again and again)
4. Now I was thinking, is there anyway we can direct get the value from Javascript to HTML? This is the code/idea that I still working with, please kindly advice me.

Javascript:

```
var screenWidth = $(window).width();
```

HTML:

```
<cc1:LineChart ID="LineChart1" runat="server" ChartWidth='<%#Bind("screenWidth") %>' ChartType="Basic" >
</cc1:LineChart>
```

Comment: Not certain about `asp.net` , though try utilizing `window.innerWidth`

Comment: send width and height as query string

Comment: @Musthaan thanks, might not be the best solution, but it did helped me solved the problem! #thinkoutsidethebox